# FCMToken always null in real device

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate Fireabase notification in iOS for 5 days.
But I can't get the fcmtoken in real device.
It always null.
Here is my code. This code is just from the firebase GitHub sample code.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[FIRApp configure];

[FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;

[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;


// Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
// show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
} else {
    // iOS 8 or later
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
        #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        //[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];
        #endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    // [END register_for_notifications]
}
return YES; }
```

Adn I know I can get the femtoken on the didRefreshRegistrationToken delegate method.
The method is fired well on the simulator, but never fired on real device.
And after [FIRApp configure], I tried to get the fcmtoken with this method [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token],but still token is null.
I have done googling as much as I can do, but get the proper answer on the google.
Please help me.
Any help would be appreciate for me

Comment: Why is the didRefreshRegistrationToken delegate method never fired on real device?

Comment: please check this answer it might help you ..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778308/unable-to-get-fcm-token-on-real-device-but-getting-on-simulator